# Estimated Time Of Arrival

Tags: android, math

I'm implementing something which will display the ETA and I need some help with displaying this correctly.

Example

```
//calculates the ETA in hours
var eta = CalculateEta(currentLocation, destination); //returns eq. 0,2169067
```

How can I display this in minutes and if the ETA is greather then 1 in hours and minutes?

Example

If my returned ETA value equals 0,2169067 I would like to display it like this:

```
"Estimated Time Of Arrival is in 21 minutes"
```

If my ETA has a value of 1,502235 I would like to display:

```
"Estimated Time Of Arrival is in 1 hour and 50 minutes"
```

Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: what exactly do you want, display(print) it?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, is it that you are having trouble converting the return value of CalculateEta() to hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: Yes, i will update my question with a example

Comment: Still confused, what format is the return value in?? is it a String?

Comment: the return value of the CalculateEta is a float value

Comment: I see,it would be much easier to convert if you made it return the value as milliseconds (as a long type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static String viaDate(float eta) {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("H 'hours,' m 'minutes,' s 'seconds,' S 'ms'", Locale.US);
    // convert to milliseconds, for some reason substract one hour, 0f results in 1:00
    Date date = new Date((long) (eta * ONE_HOUR) - ONE_HOUR);
    return format.format(date);
}

private static String manual(float eta) {
    int hour = (int) eta;
    eta =  (eta - hour) * 60;
    int minutes = (int) eta;
    eta =  (eta - minutes) * 60;
    int seconds = (int) eta;
    eta =  (eta - seconds) * 1000;
    int ms = (int) eta;
    return String.format("%d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds, %d ms", hour, minutes, seconds, ms);
}
```

Both will result in something like

```
"0 hours, 14 minutes, 2 seconds, 400 ms"
```

If you don't want to display hours only when > 0 and display "hours" instead of "hour" when > 1 then take the manual version add some `if (hour > 0) { /* add "x hours" */ }` logic

That might work with `SimpleDateFormat` as well but I was too lazy to look up what formatting options you have.